# Samba: share is not accessible for AD groups

Tags: samba, cifs, active-directory, smb, sssd

I have a CentOS server joined to an ID domain with [realm(8)](https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/8/realm/) using [sssd(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sssd). I don´t have winbind installed, though. I can log fine with AD domain users into this CentOS server. I set up samba shares in that server to try to serve files to users in the domain: I tried many configs for samba, my last one is this:

```
[global]
workgroup = MYDOMAIN
client signing = yes
client use spnego = yes
kerberos method = secrets and keytab
realm = MYDOMAIN.LOCAL.FQDN
security = ads
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
log level =3
passdb backend = tdbsam
encrypt passwords = yes

[myshare]
        path = /myshare/
        browsable =yes
        write list=@mygroup
        writable = yes
        read only = yes
        # below are 3 attempts to allow my group
        valid users=@"mygroup@mydomain.local.fqdn" @"mygroup" @"mydomain\mygroup"
```

When I go to a Windows 10 PC, I access \myCentOSserver\ and it opens the server list of shares, with myshare there. When I double click it, it gives me the pop-up saying my login failed and asks for username and password, but I´m already logged as a user member of this mygroup AD group.

My samba log file is:

```
# cat /var/log/samba/log.192.168.15.123
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.655237,  3] ../source3/smbd/oplock.c:1340(init_oplocks)
  init_oplocks: initializing messages.
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.655467,  3] ../source3/smbd/process.c:1958(process_smb)
  Transaction 0 of length 159 (0 toread)
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.655511,  3] ../source3/smbd/process.c:1538(switch_message)
  switch message SMBnegprot (pid 34286) conn 0x0
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.657361,  3] ../source3/smbd/negprot.c:628(reply_negprot)
  Requested protocol [PC NETWORK PROGRAM 1.0]
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.657416,  3] ../source3/smbd/negprot.c:628(reply_negprot)
  Requested protocol [LANMAN1.0]
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.657442,  3] ../source3/smbd/negprot.c:628(reply_negprot)
  Requested protocol [Windows for Workgroups 3.1a]
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.657465,  3] ../source3/smbd/negprot.c:628(reply_negprot)
  Requested protocol [LM1.2X002]
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.657488,  3] ../source3/smbd/negprot.c:628(reply_negprot)
  Requested protocol [LANMAN2.1]
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.657511,  3] ../source3/smbd/negprot.c:628(reply_negprot)
  Requested protocol [NT LM 0.12]
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.657534,  3] ../source3/smbd/negprot.c:628(reply_negprot)
  Requested protocol [SMB 2.002]
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.657580,  3] ../source3/smbd/negprot.c:628(reply_negprot)
  Requested protocol [SMB 2.???]
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.657823,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_negprot.c:294(smbd_smb2_request_process_negprot)
  Selected protocol SMB2_FF
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.660341,  3] ../source3/smbd/negprot.c:761(reply_negprot)
  Selected protocol SMB 2.???
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.663491,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_negprot.c:294(smbd_smb2_request_process_negprot)
  Selected protocol SMB3_11
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.676251,  3] ../auth/kerberos/kerberos_pac.c:413(kerberos_decode_pac)
  Found account name from PAC: Adriano.Pinaffo [PINAFFO, Adriano]
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.676326,  3] ../source3/auth/user_krb5.c:51(get_user_from_kerberos_info)
  Kerberos ticket principal name is [myuser@mydomain.local.fqdn]
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.678238,  3] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:3868(lp_load_ex)
  lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.678398,  3] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:547(init_globals)
  Initialising global parameters
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.678599,  3] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2782(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[global]"
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.678774,  2] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2799(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[myshare]"
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.678971,  3] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:1617(lp_add_ipc)
  adding IPC service
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.679817,  1] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2488(lp_idmap_range)
  idmap range not specified for domain '*'
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.680644,  3] ../source3/smbd/password.c:144(register_homes_share)
  Adding homes service for user 'myuser' using home directory: '/home/mydomain.local.fqdn/myuser'
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.685042,  3] ../lib/util/access.c:365(allow_access)
  Allowed connection from 192.168.15.123 (192.168.15.123)
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.685174,  3] ../source3/smbd/service.c:595(make_connection_snum)
  Connect path is '/tmp' for service [IPC$]
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.685247,  3] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:113(vfs_init_default)
  Initialising default vfs hooks
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.685297,  3] ../source3/smbd/vfs.c:139(vfs_init_custom)
  Initialising custom vfs hooks from [/[Default VFS]/]
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.685493,  3] ../source3/smbd/service.c:841(make_connection_snum)
  192.168.15.123 (ipv4:192.168.15.123:2551) connect to service IPC$ initially as user myuser (uid=1953615494, gid=1953600513) (pid 34286)
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.688823,  3] ../source3/smbd/msdfs.c:1008(get_referred_path)
  get_referred_path: |myshare| in dfs path \mycentosserver\myshare is not a dfs root.
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.688886,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3171(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_NOT_FOUND] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_ioctl.c:312
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.689039,  3] ../source3/smbd/msdfs.c:1008(get_referred_path)
  get_referred_path: |myshare| in dfs path \mycentosserver\myshare is not a dfs root.
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.689094,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3171(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_NOT_FOUND] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_ioctl.c:312
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.692620,  3] ../lib/util/access.c:365(allow_access)
  Allowed connection from 192.168.15.123 (192.168.15.123)
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.692717,  3] ../libcli/security/dom_sid.c:210(dom_sid_parse_endp)
  string_to_sid: SID @mygroup@mydomain.local.fqdn is not in a valid format
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.695607,  3] ../libcli/security/dom_sid.c:210(dom_sid_parse_endp)
  string_to_sid: SID @mygroup is not in a valid format
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.700832,  3] ../libcli/security/dom_sid.c:210(dom_sid_parse_endp)
  string_to_sid: SID @mydomain\mygroup is not in a valid format
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.702335,  2] ../source3/smbd/service.c:349(create_connection_session_info)
  user 'myuser' (from session setup) not permitted to access this share (myshare)
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.702388,  1] ../source3/smbd/service.c:521(make_connection_snum)
  create_connection_session_info failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.702462,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3171(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_tcon.c:138
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.705850,  3] ../lib/util/access.c:365(allow_access)
  Allowed connection from 192.168.15.123 (192.168.15.123)
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.705939,  3] ../libcli/security/dom_sid.c:210(dom_sid_parse_endp)
  string_to_sid: SID @mygroup@mydomain.local.fqdn is not in a valid format
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.709969,  3] ../libcli/security/dom_sid.c:210(dom_sid_parse_endp)
  string_to_sid: SID @mygroup is not in a valid format
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.714254,  3] ../libcli/security/dom_sid.c:210(dom_sid_parse_endp)
  string_to_sid: SID @mydomain\mygroup is not in a valid format
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.715363,  2] ../source3/smbd/service.c:349(create_connection_session_info)
  user 'myuser' (from session setup) not permitted to access this share (myshare)
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.715434,  1] ../source3/smbd/service.c:521(make_connection_snum)
  create_connection_session_info failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.715538,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3171(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_tcon.c:138
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.719135,  3] ../source3/smbd/msdfs.c:1008(get_referred_path)
  get_referred_path: |myshare| in dfs path \mycentosserver\myshare is not a dfs root.
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.719220,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3171(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_NOT_FOUND] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_ioctl.c:312
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.719399,  3] ../source3/smbd/msdfs.c:1008(get_referred_path)
  get_referred_path: |myshare| in dfs path \mycentosserver\myshare is not a dfs root.
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.719458,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3171(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_NOT_FOUND] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_ioctl.c:312
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.722522,  3] ../lib/util/access.c:365(allow_access)
  Allowed connection from 192.168.15.123 (192.168.15.123)
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.722632,  3] ../libcli/security/dom_sid.c:210(dom_sid_parse_endp)
  string_to_sid: SID @mygroup@mydomain.local.fqdn is not in a valid format
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.725278,  3] ../libcli/security/dom_sid.c:210(dom_sid_parse_endp)
  string_to_sid: SID @mygroup is not in a valid format
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.729162,  3] ../libcli/security/dom_sid.c:210(dom_sid_parse_endp)
  string_to_sid: SID @mydomain\mygroup is not in a valid format
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.730606,  2] ../source3/smbd/service.c:349(create_connection_session_info)
  user 'myuser' (from session setup) not permitted to access this share (myshare)
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.730700,  1] ../source3/smbd/service.c:521(make_connection_snum)
  create_connection_session_info failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.730803,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3171(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_tcon.c:138
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.734060,  3] ../lib/util/access.c:365(allow_access)
  Allowed connection from 192.168.15.123 (192.168.15.123)
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.734146,  3] ../libcli/security/dom_sid.c:210(dom_sid_parse_endp)
  string_to_sid: SID @mygroup@mydomain.local.fqdn is not in a valid format
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.737530,  3] ../libcli/security/dom_sid.c:210(dom_sid_parse_endp)
  string_to_sid: SID @mygroup is not in a valid format
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.743056,  3] ../libcli/security/dom_sid.c:210(dom_sid_parse_endp)
  string_to_sid: SID @mydomain\mygroup is not in a valid format
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.745052,  2] ../source3/smbd/service.c:349(create_connection_session_info)
  user 'myuser' (from session setup) not permitted to access this share (myshare)
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.745105,  1] ../source3/smbd/service.c:521(make_connection_snum)
  create_connection_session_info failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.745176,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3171(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_tcon.c:138
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.749224,  3] ../source3/smbd/msdfs.c:1008(get_referred_path)
  get_referred_path: |myshare| in dfs path \mycentosserver\myshare is not a dfs root.
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.749304,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3171(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_NOT_FOUND] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_ioctl.c:312
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.752605,  3] ../lib/util/access.c:365(allow_access)
  Allowed connection from 192.168.15.123 (192.168.15.123)
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.752686,  3] ../libcli/security/dom_sid.c:210(dom_sid_parse_endp)
  string_to_sid: SID @mygroup@mydomain.local.fqdn is not in a valid format
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.755528,  3] ../libcli/security/dom_sid.c:210(dom_sid_parse_endp)
  string_to_sid: SID @mygroup is not in a valid format
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.760950,  3] ../libcli/security/dom_sid.c:210(dom_sid_parse_endp)
  string_to_sid: SID @mydomain\mygroup is not in a valid format
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.762243,  2] ../source3/smbd/service.c:349(create_connection_session_info)
  user 'myuser' (from session setup) not permitted to access this share (myshare)
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.762293,  1] ../source3/smbd/service.c:521(make_connection_snum)
  create_connection_session_info failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.762362,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3171(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_tcon.c:138
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.765697,  3] ../lib/util/access.c:365(allow_access)
  Allowed connection from 192.168.15.123 (192.168.15.123)
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.765791,  3] ../libcli/security/dom_sid.c:210(dom_sid_parse_endp)
  string_to_sid: SID @mygroup@mydomain.local.fqdn is not in a valid format
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.768600,  3] ../libcli/security/dom_sid.c:210(dom_sid_parse_endp)
  string_to_sid: SID @mygroup is not in a valid format
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.773398,  3] ../libcli/security/dom_sid.c:210(dom_sid_parse_endp)
  string_to_sid: SID @mydomain\mygroup is not in a valid format
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.774735,  2] ../source3/smbd/service.c:349(create_connection_session_info)
  user 'myuser' (from session setup) not permitted to access this share (myshare)
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.774806,  1] ../source3/smbd/service.c:521(make_connection_snum)
  create_connection_session_info failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.774926,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3171(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_tcon.c:138
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.779205,  3] ../source3/smbd/msdfs.c:1008(get_referred_path)
  get_referred_path: |myshare| in dfs path \mycentosserver\myshare is not a dfs root.
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.779280,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3171(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_NOT_FOUND] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_ioctl.c:312
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.783652,  3] ../lib/util/access.c:365(allow_access)
  Allowed connection from 192.168.15.123 (192.168.15.123)
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.783720,  3] ../libcli/security/dom_sid.c:210(dom_sid_parse_endp)
  string_to_sid: SID @mygroup@mydomain.local.fqdn is not in a valid format
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.786662,  3] ../libcli/security/dom_sid.c:210(dom_sid_parse_endp)
  string_to_sid: SID @mygroup is not in a valid format
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.792866,  3] ../libcli/security/dom_sid.c:210(dom_sid_parse_endp)
  string_to_sid: SID @mydomain\mygroup is not in a valid format
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.794993,  2] ../source3/smbd/service.c:349(create_connection_session_info)
  user 'myuser' (from session setup) not permitted to access this share (myshare)
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.795046,  1] ../source3/smbd/service.c:521(make_connection_snum)
  create_connection_session_info failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
[2019/02/25 18:25:13.795318,  3] ../source3/smbd/smb2_server.c:3171(smbd_smb2_request_error_ex)
  smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: smbd_smb2_request_error_ex: idx[1] status[NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED] || at ../source3/smbd/smb2_tcon.c:138
[2019/02/25 18:25:24.362427,  3] ../source3/smbd/service.c:1120(close_cnum)
  192.168.15.123 (ipv4:192.168.15.123:2551) closed connection to service IPC$
[2019/02/25 18:25:24.368723,  3] ../source3/smbd/server_exit.c:236(exit_server_common)
  Server exit (NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET)
```

It said for the 3 attempts to use an AD group it *is not in a valid format*. Now, if I put my username directly (no "@" sign) in the `smb.conf` valid users section, or `@"Domain Users"` I can access the share with no problem. So, how do I specify only one AD group?

Comment: Pretty sure this line is incorrect:
passdb backend = tdbsam
You're doing authentication through AD, not a text file.  I haven't solved this one yet myself, but this is what it looks like on an LDAP-based system.
passdb backend = ldapsam:"ldap://ibm10.accouning.megacorp.com"